# What does (char)0 mean?

Tags: c#

```
private void btnShowPassword_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    txtPassword.PasswordChar = (char)0;
}
```

Can someone please explain what `(char)0` means in the above context?

Comment: It's casting the integer `0` to a `char`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Comment: It resets the PasswordChar property to its default value (U+0000), so that the typed text is visible again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

> **TextBox.PasswordChar Property**
>
> [...]
>
> The character used to mask characters entered in a single-line TextBox control. Set the value of this property to '0' (U+0000) if you do not want the control to mask characters as they are typed. The default value is '0' (U+0000).

`U+0000` is the character at the Unicode code point 0, which is exactly what `(char)0` in C# creates. [Alternative ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences) to write this would be

```
txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0';
txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\u0000';
txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\x0';
```

Comment: Or `= default(char)`. Since the default of any value type is all zero's.

Answer (score 2):

It's casting `int` 0 to `Char` 0. You can't set the `PasswordChar` property with a number as it expects a Char.

Setting `PasswordChar` to '0' will actually reset the property which is a password mask. thus revealing the password. Hence why the previous developer called the name of the event `btnShowPassword_MouseDown`.

If you were curious you can convert Numbers to Characters here is a look up guide:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) type represents a unicode (UTF-16) character. The underlying representation is a 16-bit number, so it can be [converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) (through explicit cast) to and from an integer.

The expression `(char)0` casts the integer value `0` to the corresponding unicode character `'\0'`, which is the default value.